# Redemption.dll and delphi how to send email

Tags: email, delphi, outlook-redemption

I have the following code in Delphi 10 Seattle using Redemption.dll. However, the email is stuck in my inbox until I press "Send/Receive". How do I get it to send email automatically?

```
procedure TForm1.sendMail(sendername, senderemail, subject, reciever,
  message: WideString; Html_or_text: Boolean);
const
  olMailItem = 0;
var
  olApp, OlNameSpace, OlItem, rdSafeItem, rdUtils: variant;
  OutlookApplication1 : OleVariant;
  NameSpace : OleVariant;
  AddressLists : OleVariant;
  AddressList : OleVariant;
  AddressEntries : OleVariant;
  folder:RDOFolder;
  m  : RDOMail;
  mailitem: SafeMailItem;
begin
  folder := session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
  m := folder.Items.Add(olMailItem);
  m.To_ := reciever;
  m.Subject := subject;
  //rdomail.SentOnBehalfOfEmailAddress = ;
  m.SenderName := sendername;
  m.Body := message;
  m.SenderEmailAddress := senderemail;
  //m.Save();
  m.Send;
end;
```

Comment: Please format your code do make it easier to read. Your chances for an answer will improve by this.

Answer (score 4):

This is to be expected for a cached profile - unless you are using an online Exchange profile, it is Outlook that will need to send the message.

You can use `Namespace.SendAndReceive` or `SyncObject.Start` in the Outlook Object Model.

See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#1 for more details.

Answer (score -2):

The e-mail is being added to the inbox. Instead it should be added to the outbox and then Outlook will automatically send it.

Replace

```
folder := session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
```

with

```
folder := session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox);
```

Comment: Absolutely not. Outbox is an eye candy - it does nothing. A message can be submitted from any folder.